# How to display a word from different lines?

Tags: bash, bash4

I wanna be able to display every line that has the word from input read.
Now Im able to display the index position of the input read word.

```
echo "Filename"
read file

echo "A word"
read word

echo $file | awk '{print index($0,"'"$word"'")}'
```

Comment: why dont you use `grep` ?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Can you give me any example, on how to use grep?

Comment: As per your question `grep $word $file` will output lines in `$file` containing `$word`

Comment: If you want line numbers too, you can use `grep` like this: `grep -in $word $file`

Comment: If you make it clear what your desired output is, then we will be able to help you better.

Comment: upvote for grep with line numbers `grep -n $word $file`

Answer (score 1):

as requested here is an example of how you could use grep.
The following command will use wget to fetch the content of this stackoverflow webpage, the `-O -` option tells wget to output the html into std out, which then gets piped into `grep -n grep`.
grep matches the number of instances the term "grep" appears in the html and then outputs with the corresponding line number where the match occurs - and highlights the match.

```
wget -O - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691506/how-to-display-a-word-from-different-lines | grep -n grep
```

e.g. When I run in my terminal (ignoring the wget related output) `grep -n grep`gives:

```
42: <span class="comment-copy">why dont you use <code>grep</code> ?</span>
468: <span class="comment-copy">@nu11p01n73R Can you give me any example, on how to use grep?</span>
495: <span class="comment-copy">As per your question <code>grep $word $file</code> will output lines in <code>$file</code> containing <code>$word</code></span>
521: <span class="comment-copy">If you want line numbers too, you can use <code>grep</code> like this: <code>grep -in $word $file</code></span>
```

Note stackoverflow syntax highlighting is different to what you get in terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print also the line number

```
read -p 'Filename? ' fname
read -p 'Word to search? ' word
awk /"$word"/'{print NR, $0}' "$fname"
```

If you don't want the line number

```
read -p 'Filename? ' fname
read -p 'Word to search? ' word
awk /"$word"/ "$fname"
```

BTW, what everyone told you is "use grep", but look at this

```
% time for i in {1..10000} ; do grep alias .bashrc > /dev/null ; done

real    0m22.665s
user    0m2.672s
sys     0m3.564s
% time for i in {1..10000} ; do mawk /alias/ .bashrc > /dev/null ; done

real    0m21.951s
user    0m3.412s
sys     0m3.636s
```

Of course `gawk` is slower, in this case 27.9 seconds.